# Delete from cursor position to end of text object

Tags: cursor-motions

I often find myself in this situation:

```
\foo{\bar abc \baz{def} more stuff}
          ↑
```

and I want to change anything from the cursor position to the *correct* enclosing brace. In simple cases, `ct}` works fine, but not here, as it would yield

```
\foo{\bar } more stuff}
          ↑
```

In other simple cases, when I am happy to change the whole content of the braces, I can use text objects, i.e. `ci}`, to change everything correctly:

```
\foo{}
     ↑
```

But how do I get to

```
\foo{\bar }
          ↑
```

ideally somehow using text objects  (i.e. `i}`), so that it works well in general?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [ninja-feet.vim](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-ninja-feet) plugin by [Tom McDonald](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/64/tommcdo) adds this functionality to Vim.

With it installed, add <kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>]</kbd> between the operator and text object to specify which end you wish edit: press <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>]</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>}</kbd> to perform the edit you describe.

Comment: Unfortunate that it’s a plugin, but otherwise, perfect!

Answer (score 4):

when I do `c2t}` it seems to work, but this is assuming you know that it's the second bracket.

Comment: I was wondering why someone wouldn't just use the repeat command with `.` so that would be `ct}.`

Comment: Note that you can do `c2t}` (change to the destination of `2t}`) or `2ct}` (change twice to the destination of `t}`) which will change how the `.` command will repeat your command. In general it is better to use `c2t}` as Ibn Rushd said I think it is more consistent.

Comment: Damn my comment was 31 seconds too late :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind having the retype the closing `}` would:

> c]}

do what you want? Although I think I prefer v]} so I can see what it's going to change first ...

Comment: Nice! This seems like the best solution for the specific example. N.B. `]}` is an exclusive motion (see `:help exclusive`), so you *won't* have to re-type the closing `}` if you use `c]}`, only if you use the visual mode alternative you suggest.

Comment: Is it? Oh .. it looks as though it's highlighting the } when I use `v`, but not deleting it with the `c` ... TIL etc. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes! At least when it’s braces. I will reach to the ninja feet plugin since there are text objects like `t` (for HTML tags) where `]` does not seem to work (or does it?).

Answer (score 0):

Use the change command, using search (/) semantics:
"Change until the next occurrence of right brace":

```
c/}
```

Comment: That does not work, as the next right brace is not the next *enclosing* right brace. Also, for a single character, `ct}` is faster than `c/}`.